# UINavigationController have to set view height to 548 on 3.5 inch screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I think a have a special case here, since I've a UIViewController with a IB view set to 4 inch size and add a UINavigationController with addChildViewController (Facebook/Path like slider menu). The Problem I'm facing now is that if I run the app the height of the UINavigationController view is 372 when setting

```
containerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
```

I've to set the height to 548 to get the correct height of 460 on a 3.5 inch device. How can I fix that?

[image: Simulator screenshot]

I als register an event on the UIBarButtonItem to slide away the screen with

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(268, 0, 320, 460);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
```

When clicking on the button the UIView is set to the correct height but I'm using the exact same size of `(268, 0, 320, 460)` for CGRectMake.

When I'm setting the frame after

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

it is working by using 460 for the height, why is this working, I think iOS is performing the display size adjustment only after `makeKeyAndVisible`

Comment: One thing you can do is add two views to the baseView, the top one with 44 width and the one below with the rest and add your `UINavigationBar` to the `UIView` which is above.

Comment: in a somewhat similar situation, this saved the day .. -  (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews { // horrible fix, to make it position properly on all (most?? many??) devices! self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0); }