# UINavigationController view is cut off when 3.5 inch screen

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

I got a problem when using UINavigationController in 3.5 inch screen. in 4 inch screen, there is no problem. the screen will look like this

[image]

But in 3.5 inch screen, it became like this

[image]

The bottom part is cut off. I looked for other similar questions here ( ex. [UINavigationController have to set view height to 548 on 3.5 inch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359769/uinavigationcontroller-have-to-set-view-height-to-548-on-3-5-inch-screen) ) But didn't get a clear answer. Anyone knows how to solve it? Thx in advance.

[update]: solved the problem by:
in viewDidLoad: 
self.devicesettingnavigationcontroller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

Comment: good to know you solved it yourself. Great going. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is an autosizing option. You have to do something like. I think this is what is causing this issue.

[image]

Then do this:

[image]

Hope this is what you are looking for. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Please try this:
[image]

Hope this works. Thanks.